# Angular material mat grid list not expanding

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am new to the angular-material libary (and material design spec in general), I have used bootstrap for years, so am not sure I am implementing mat-grid-list correctly, but I have the follwing:

```html
<mat-card>
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile-header>Clocked In</mat-grid-tile-header>
        <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item> 
                <button  mat-raised-button color="warn">
                        {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                </button>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile-header>Clocked Out</mat-grid-tile-header>
        <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item> 
                <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
                    {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                </button>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

This is based off of the angular-material example, to which I have included a working stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cccnjp?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html

As you can see, the buttons have been rendered inside the mat-grid-tile-header and the mat-card has not expanded to accomodate the content provided (as I would expect)

EDIT: So, I did try using the rowHeight="fit" attribute on the mat-grid-list but this doesn't render any content, I would expect this to expand the height of mat-grid-list depending on content, but this is not working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cccnjp-ylmzf9?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.html

**UPDATE:** *ugly working solution*

So I managed to acheive this with some (quite ugly) css...

```
<mat-card class="height100p">
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
    <mat-grid-tile class="mat-grid-tile-custom">
        <mat-grid-tile-header>Clocked In</mat-grid-tile-header>
        <mat-list class="custom-mat-list">
            <mat-list-item> 
                <button  mat-raised-button color="warn">
                        {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                </button>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile class="mat-grid-tile-custom">
        <mat-grid-tile-header>Clocked Out</mat-grid-tile-header>
        <mat-list class="custom-mat-list">
            <mat-list-item> 
                <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
                    {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                </button>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

```
.height100p {
    height: 100%;
}
.mat-grid-tile-custom {
    overflow: visible!important;
}

.custom-mat-list { /* this is bad! */
    padding-top: 50%!important;
}

.mat-grid-tile-custom .mat-figure {
    align-items: unset!important;
}
```

As you can see, the glaring error/problem here is the .custom-mat-list with a padding-top of 50%, this will be different between browsers, although technically this works, I don't think its a long term solution, if anuone has any thoughts/improvements or suggestions I would be very grateful.

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cccnjp-3dieg1?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.css

Comment: According to the docs, `rowHeight-"fit"` will only work when the grid list's parent container has a height set on it, but I tried that and it still didn't work. You can try setting `rowHeight` to a physical value such as `484px` or a `calc()`, but this might not be workable in a real-world app.

Comment: Yea, I added some above code/css to get this working as I want, but its not pretty.

Comment: This will work and is less "bad": 

    .custom-mat-list { /* this is bad! */
      position: absolute;
      top: 48px;
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as per hendrathings answer, what I want to display is not to material design spec. So in order to do this, I used material+flexbox with the template:

```
<div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="50%" >
        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex  >
            <mat-toolbar color="primary" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <span>Clocked In</span>
            </mat-toolbar>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="50%" >
        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex >
            <mat-toolbar color="primary"fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
                    <span>Clocked Out</span>
            </mat-toolbar>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="clockingStatus">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="50%" >
        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex  >
            <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of clockingStatus.clocked_in"
                fxLayoutAlign="center center" > 
                        <button mat-raised-button color="warn">
                                {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                        </button>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="50%" >
        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
            <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of clockingStatus.clocked_out"
                fxLayoutAlign="center center" > 
                        <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
                                {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                        </button>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

`mat-grid-list` and `mat-list` layout component. It's not use to be content each other. You should pick one as a layout.

For example you trying combine `mat-button-toggle` and `mat-button`. like this:

```
<mat-button-toggle>Toggle me!
  <button mat-button>Click me!</button>
</mat-button-toggle>
```

it doesn't work like that, right?

if your purpose to use 2 dimension, you can use grid only like this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2"  gutterSize="30px" rowHeight="5:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile-header>Clocked In</mat-grid-tile-header>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <mat-grid-tile-header>Clocked In</mat-grid-tile-header>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile >
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          User Text Out
        </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

**TL;DR;**

Don't combine `list view` and `grid`, choose one. Or you will break material design spec, see grid [Documentation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/grid-lists.html#grid-lists-specs).

### UPDATE

For loop data with to listview, use tab layout. check this out for sample:

```
<div class="example-container" [class.example-is-mobile]="mobileQuery.matches" *ngIf="shouldRun">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="example-toolbar">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <h1 class="example-app-name">Responsive App</h1>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container" [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'" [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="Clocked In">
        <h1>Clocked In</h1>
        <mat-list *ngFor="let user of usersIn">
          <mat-list-item>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn">
            {{user}}
        </button>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Clocked Out">
        <h1>Clocked Out</h1>
        <mat-list>
          <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of usersOut">
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn">
            {{user}}
        </button>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!shouldRun">Please open on Stackblitz to see result</div>
```

Link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cccnjp-ufqtvj?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.html

Comment: So this renders perfectly, however my content is dynamic, how do I force dynamically rendered content into a certain column? Example shown here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cccnjp-3dieg1?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html

Comment: @crooksey, then what you need not grid. material doesn't work with 2 list in each split 2 column. what you need play with tab. if you do split into 2 columns and show list with listview then you break rule material design. https://material.io/guidelines/components/grid-lists.html. see my update for using tab.